# Cache Token on Azure Functions (3rd party Token)

Tags: azure, function, api, token

I am using HTTP Trigger Azure Functions for getting/posting data on a third party API service. This API service needs firstly to authenticate and then get a Token for using another service. So , I want to cache the token. Problem is that once I deploy to Azure, it asks me for an "empty paramter" called S. Strange as it sounds. Every advice is welcome. Thanks! Cache code is :

```
            /*
            object cacheKeyDefault = MemoryCache.Default.Get($"{userId+usuario + canal + device}");

            if (cacheKeyDefault == null)
            {

                //Genero póliza con el tiempo obtenido del Environment
                CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy()
                {
                    AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(double.Parse(tokenTimeout)))
                };

                //Genero Json de request para Token
                RequestToken tokenRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestToken>(requestBody);
                string tokenrequestJs = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenRequest);
                log.LogInformation($"tokenrequestJs: {tokenrequestJs} ");

                //Obtengo el Session Token
                string responseTokenJs = RestAPI.Ejecutar(url + accionToken, Method.POST, tokenrequestJs);
                log.LogInformation("Response Token: " + responseTokenJs);

                //Lo agrego dinámicamente
                dynamic tokenResponseDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseTokenJs);
                dynamic SessionToken = tokenResponseDynamic.SessionToken;
                string SessionTokenString = SessionToken;
                reqBody.Btinreq.Token = SessionToken;
               

             

                MemoryCache.Default.Set($"{userId+usuario +canal+device}", SessionTokenString, cip);

            }
            else   
            {

                dynamic SessionToken = cacheKeyDefault;
                reqBody.Btinreq.Token = SessionToken;

            }
```

Comment: I believe you must use Azure Redis Cache for it

Comment: the "thing" is that you're function won't be running all the time. So there's a high chance the token will never be cached

Comment: Problem is that once I deploy to Azure, it asks me for an "empty paramter" called S."- could you provide a bit more code ? Since your question is not clear

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat rest of the code is unnecesary. Believe me, works well without the cache code. But when I add the cache part, throws a 400 bad request and asks for a paramter named S.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio . I'll look for that. I really think that once I deploy, in Azure portal does not work the System.Caching . Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the full error details?